# how to express Chebyshev sequence constants for function approximations in an interval other than [-1,1]?

Tags: math, polynomials, polynomial-math, maple, approximation

To approximate the function with Cheboshev polynomials, it is necessary to operate on the interval [-1,1]. How can these constants be recalculated if I want to approximate on another interval?

specifically, I use maple and the following loop:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWT74.png)

but I don't know how to modify the function to calculate in an interval, for example [-pi,pi]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function `f(x)` defined on `[-pi, pi]` then you can transform it to a function `g(u)` on `[-1, 1]` by a linear change of variable:

```
u = -1 + 2 * (x + pi) / (2*pi).
```

Then you can approximate `g` by a polynomial `P(u)`, and then transform `P(u)` to the polynomial `Q(x)` by the inverse change of variables:

```
x = -pi + (2*pi) * (u + 1) / 2.
```